# How to do event handling for android and iOS in react native's new architecture for fabric components?

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native, objective-c++

I am trying to create a `Fabric` component. I have got it working for the most part. The only issue I am facing is I am not able to get click listener to work for a `fabric` component.

I created a spec file

```
import type {HostComponent, ViewProps} from 'react-native';
import type {DirectEventHandler} from 'react-native/Libraries/Types/CodegenTypes';
import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';

type Event = Readonly<{
  value: string;
}>;

interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  text: string;
   onClickHandler?: BubblingEventHandler<Event>; ////Event name should start with on
}

export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
  'MyButtonView',
) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;
```

For `android` my `fabric` component looks like as follows

```
public class MyButtonView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton {

    public MyButtonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        configureViews();
    }

    private void configureViews(){
        setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        setOnClickListener(view -> {
            onReceiveNativeEvent();
        });
    }

    public void onReceiveNativeEvent() {
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putString("message", "MyMessage");
        ReactContext reactContext = (ReactContext)getContext();
        reactContext.getJSModule(RCTModernEventEmitter.class)
                .receiveEvent(getId(),getId(),"onClickHandler",true,0,event,1);

    }
}
```

Not sure what to pass `first param as int`, `canCoalesceEvent`, `customCoalesceKey` and `category` in `receiveEvent`

In `ViewManager` I did add following code as well

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
    Log.i("here55","999999");
    return MapBuilder.of("onClickHandler",
            MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onClickHandler")
    );
}
```

For `android` I am not getting the `callback` from `native` `android` to `js` side

I am following https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android but it was for the old architecture and I think is not applicable for `fabric` components

Same for `iOS` https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-ios, the doc is not very helpful for the new architecture

For `iOS`, I created the `header` and `objective-c++` file

Typically if we want to add property we do this

```
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(text, NSString)
```

Not sure how to do it for event handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## iOS

Assuming native spec you posted is correct (I'm not really familiar with TypeScript + Codegen duo) when you run `pod install` command in your `ios/` directory codegen should generate `EventEmitters` cpp file (+ header) in `React-Codegen` pod (you can see below how to find it in XCode)

[link to the screenshot with Pods structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x52mg.png)

You can then use these classes in your `Objective-C++` code to emit the events:

```c
if (_eventEmitter != nullptr) {
    std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const facebook::react::$$NAME OF YOUR EVENT EMITTER TYPE$$>(_eventEmitter)
        ->onEvent(facebook::react::$$NAME OF YOUR EVENT EMITTER TYPE::OnEvent{.value = $$VALUE$$});
}
```

See links below to see how it is done in [`react-native-screens`](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens)

1. [Native component spec in `Flow`](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/main/src/fabric/ScreenNativeComponent.js)
2. [Event emission in Obj-C++ code](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/cc5de7ba28e90ecce9bbb3464ef0a625eaae032f/ios/RNSScreen.mm#L316-L334)
3. [Event exposure in screen manager](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/cc5de7ba28e90ecce9bbb3464ef0a625eaae032f/ios/RNSScreen.mm#L1175) - I'm not quite sure if this line is necessary, haven't tested it out yet.

## Android

1. To trigger codegen just run native build.
2. Define native event class as [done here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/main/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/events/ScreenAppearEvent.kt)
3. Take a look here for [how to dispatch event](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/ce84df60227a02e1e505e1a494ea1ca829788d58/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenFragment.kt#L198-L215)
4. [Export your event types](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/blob/ce84df60227a02e1e505e1a494ea1ca829788d58/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/ScreenViewManager.kt#L164-L181)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the documentation is so terse right now, not even sure if I'm using the new architecture or not, but its working.

Here are the steps for Android in Java flavour.

Step 1 - Define the Specs

```
type CustomEvent = Readonly<{
  status: string;
}>;

export interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  onStatusChange?: DirectEventHandler<CustomEvent>;
}
```

Step 2 - Define Event Class

```
public class CustomEvent extends Event<CustomEvent> {

    public static final String EVENT_NAME = "topCustomEvent";
    private String status;

    CustomEvent(int viewId, String _status) {
        super(viewId);
        this.status = _status;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEventName() {
        return EVENT_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatch(RCTEventEmitter rctEventEmitter) {
        super.dispatch(rctEventEmitter);
    }

    @Override
    protected WritableMap getEventData() {
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putString("status", this.status);
        return event;
    }
}
```

Step 3 - Export/Register Event Type in ViewManager class by overriding its  **getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants** method.

```
@Override
public @Nullable
Map getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants() {
  Map<String, Object> export = super.getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants();
  if (export == null) {
    export = MapBuilder.newHashMap();
  }
  export.put(CustomEvent.EVENT_NAME, MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onStatusChange"));
  return export;
}
```

Step 4- Create dispatchEvent method, call it wherever need to pass event to JS.

```
private void dispatchEvent(String status) {
    EventDispatcher mEventDispatcher = UIManagerHelper.getEventDispatcherForReactTag((ReactContext)this.ctx, getId());
    mEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(getId(), status));
}
```

Step 5 - Setup callback in JS where events are to be processed.

```
onStatusChange={(event) => {console.log('ontatusChange: '+event.nativeEvent.status);}}
```

Step 6 - Build App, codgen should occur as explained [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/pillars-codegen).