# Cannot find EventEmitter for receiveEvent Error - Fabric Component when returning event to javascript

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a React Native Fabric module with the new architecture. It has to return some information to JavaScript. I'm following the [marked answer here as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73019490/) for Android, but I can't get this working. I always get the error:

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactNoCrashSoftException: Cannot find EventEmitter for receiveEvent: SurfaceId[1] ReactTag[-1] UIManagerType[2] EventName[topAppear]
```

The code I'm using, based on the provided answer before, is the following:

In Manager.kt class:

```
override fun getExportedCustomDirectEventTypeConstants(): MutableMap<String, Any> {
    return MapBuilder.of(
        ScreenAppearEvent.EVENT_NAME,
        MapBuilder.of("registrationName", "onAppear")
    )
}
```

The event class:

```
class ScreenAppearEvent(surfaceId: Int, viewId: Int) : Event<ScreenAppearEvent>(surfaceId, viewId) {
override fun getEventName() = EVENT_NAME

override fun getCoalescingKey(): Short = 0

override fun getEventData(): WritableMap? = Arguments.createMap()

companion object {
    const val EVENT_NAME = "topAppear"
}
```

}

Here a function of the class which processes the view event. It gets called correctly. `reactContext` and `viewId` are parsed from the view itself as class constructor params.

```
private fun dispatchEvent() {
    val surfaceId = UIManagerHelper.getSurfaceId(reactContext)

    val eventDispatcher: EventDispatcher? = UIManagerHelper.getEventDispatcherForReactTag(reactContext, viewId)
    val lifecycleEvent: Event<*> = ScreenAppearEvent(surfaceId, viewId);
    eventDispatcher?.dispatchEvent(lifecycleEvent)
}
```

The interface in TypeScript. It should return the `currentTime` value, I'm not returning values from Android at the moment in order to avoid complicating things further.

```
type ProgressEvent = Readonly<{
  currentTime: string;
}>


export interface NativeProps extends ViewProps {
  source?: string;
  autoPlay?: boolean;
  play?: boolean;
  onAppear?: DirectEventHandler<ProgressEvent>;
}
```

What am I missing here? I would appreciate some help. I tried to include `dispatchModern` or `dispatch` in the event class, but I still get the same error.